# Show $A : \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let *A* be a matrix defined by  \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
Show that $$A: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2 $$
Is a Linear Transformation.

I have been working this problem and I am just lost with even where to begin.

Comment: Begin with definitions: what does it mean for a transformation to be linear? Then verify those conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:-** consider the standard basis for both domain and codomain vector space.

$T(1,0,0) = 4(1,0)+1(0,1) = (4,1)$

$T(0,1,0) = 1(1,0)+0(0,1) =(1,0)$

$T(0,0,1) = 0(1,0)+1(0,1) =(0,1)$

With this data just find the linear transformation .